# Chemical potential of an intrinsic semiconductor

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, chemical-potential

I was going through an article called ["The chemical potential of an ideal intrinsic semiconductor"](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1629090) and I just cannot understand how the author gets that expression for the chemical potential. I know how to find the standard result for the chemical potential with equating the carrier densities. In another [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/0038-1098(86)90803-3) of this author, he gives carrier densities which comes out with the new treatment but using those densities in the standard way to find chemical potential still gives a different result. Can anyone help me understand the logic to find that expression for the chemical potential?

Comment: The relationship between the chemical potential and the Fermi energy is, well, complicated. I did not read the article, but in my mind the references are missing several important papers from the 1950's discussing that point.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by the phrase "the relationship between the chemical potential and the Fermi energy". I don't think this has anything to do with Fermi energy. The author talks about how the Fermi-Dirac distribution function breaks down when the temperature goes to zero so he writes down new expressions for the probability of finding a carrier in valence and conduction band, then calculates the chemical potential again.

Comment: Lets start at T>0 - do you think the chemical potential and the Fermi energy are the same?

Comment: I don't think that they are the same thing and Fermi energy is only defined at absolute zero so can we really talk about Fermi energy at T>0?

Comment: Since the Fermi-Dirac function needs a Fermi energy, the Fermi energy is most definitely not defined only at absolute zero.

Comment: You might be talking about Fermi level and not Fermi energy. But still, I cannot see the relation of this with my question. I want to understand which road one follows to find the chemical potential of the semiconductor in the grand canonical ensemble.

Comment: Equation 8 in the newer paper is the same as Equation 17 in the older paper. Which equations are you trying to reconcile?

Comment: Exactly those same equations. I cannot seem to figure out where those extra alphas are coming from.

Comment: In the older paper, Eguation 13 is for the canonical ensemble, Equation 17 is in the grand canonical ensemble. I fully agree that Eq. 17 is not well explained, and replicating the derivation in the grand canonical ensemble just isn't high on my priority list...

Answer (score -1):

It would be 0 because across the intristic semiconductor the number of charges at a cross section area will be the same everywhere.